# Setting JTextField visible on JRadioButton Click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm creating a GUI in Netbeans and I want to set a text field to appear when a radio button is selected. For some reason, the radio button click is detected, but the text field does not appear upon selection. Any suggestions on how to handle this problem? My code is pasted below. The text field is called newContainerNameInput, and the radio button is newContainerRadioButton:

```
    containersButtonGroup.add(newContainerRadioButton);
    newContainerRadioButton.setText("Create a new container");
    newContainerRadioButton.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
            newContainerRadioButtonItemStateChanged(evt);
        }
    });
    newContainerRadioButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            newContainerRadioButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    newContainerNameInput.setText("Enter new container name here");
    newContainerNameInput.setVisible(false);
```

---

```
private void newContainerRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
    System.out.println("test");
    newContainerNameInput.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: does your private method run? how does the rest of your code look? also: why do you pass event as a parameter to your private method?

Comment: @Stultuske yep, the private method runs when I run the debugger. And Netbeans actually autogenerates that code so I can't edit the actual actionPerformed method, I can only edit what's inside the newContainerRadioButtonActionPerformed.

Comment: `newContainerNameInput`has been added to your layout, right? Share some code of how you add text and button to your view?

Comment: Yes, I have         newContainerNameInput = new javax.swing.JTextField(); and then .addComponent(newContainerNameInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 291, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)) when I create a new GroupLayout

Comment: when you select the right `RadioButton`, do you have console output..? That means is the word `"test"` is printing..?

Comment: @Ramesh-X yes, the method runs and I get console output, but the text field doesn't appear. But if I take out the "newContainerNameInput.setVisible(false)" in the constructor, the text input field is visible.

Comment: Are you creating this class by extending `JFrame`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace following code in the `ActionListener` of `RadioButton`

```
private void newContainerRadioButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                        
  System.out.println("test");
  newContainerNameInput.setVisible(true);
  revalidate();
}
```

`revalidate()` is doing 2 things. First `invalidate()` and `validate()`. By doing this your components get marked invalid and validated again. That means layout again.. For more see [`javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate())

Comment: Thank you! That worked and thanks for the explanation!